# Get data out of a file without iterating through it multiple times

Tags: python, function, file, python-3.x

I've created the following function to pull data out of a file. It works ok, but gets very slow for larger files.

```
def get_data(file, indexes, data_start, sieve_first = is_float):
    file_list = list(file)
    for i in indexes:
        d_line = i+data_start
        for line in file_list[d_line:]:
            if sieve_first(line.strip().split(',')[0]):
                yield file_list[d_line].strip()
                d_line += 1
            else:
                break

def is_float(f):
    try:
        float(str(f))
    except:
        return False
    else:
        return True

with open('my_data') as f:
    data = get_data(f, index_list, 3)
```

The file might look like this (line numbers added for clarity):

```
line 1234567: # <-- INDEX
line 1234568: # +1
line 1234569: # +2
line 1234570:      8, 17.0, 23, 6487.6
line 1234571:      8, 17.0, 23, 6487.6
line 1234572:      8, 17.0, 23, 6487.6
line 1234572:
line 1234572:
line 1234572:
```

With the above example, lines 1234570 through 1234572 will be yielded.

Since my files are large, there are a couple things I don't like about my function.

1. First is that it reads the entire file into memory; I do this so I can use line indexing in order to parse the data out.
2. Second is that the same lines in the file are iterated over many times- this gets very expensive for a large file.

I have fiddled around trying to use iterators to get through the file a single time, but haven't been able to crack it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just do `for line in file` instead of `list(file)`

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, but if `file` doesn't support indexing, the rest of the function would not work.

Comment: If the file didn't support indexing, then how are you doing `file[d_line:]`?

Comment: @cricket_007 the line `file = list(file)` turns it into a `list`.

Comment: bad variable name but yeah it's a list

Comment: @kmario23 sorry- yes that is a bad variable name. i will change it.

Comment: @RickTeachey I know what what `list()` returns :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want a small portion of the file, I would use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). This function will not store any data but the data you want in memory.

Here's an example:

```
from itertools import islice

def yield_specific_lines_from_file(filename, start, stop):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as ifile:
        for line in islice(ifile, start, stop):
            yield line

lines = list(yield_specific_lines_from_file('test.txt', 10, 20))
```

If you use Python 3.3 or newer, you can also simplify this by using the [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) statement:

```
from itertools import islice

def yield_specific_lines_from_file(filename, start, stop):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as ifile:
        yield from islice(ifile, start, stop)

lines = list(yield_specific_lines_from_file('test.txt', 10, 20))
```

This will not cache the lines you've already read from the file though. If you want to to this, I suggest that you store all read lines in a dictionary with the line number as key, and only pull the data from the file if needed.

Comment: looks like `islice` is what i needed. still have to iterate through multiple times, but it's a lot less expensive this way. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Out of left field a bit.  But if you have control over your files you could move the data to an sqlite3 db.

Also take a look at mmap and linecache.  I imagine these last two are just wrappers around random access files.  i.e. you could roll your own by scanning the files once, then building an index->offset lookup table and using seek.

Some of these approaches assume you have some control of the files you're reading?

Also depends on whether you read a lot and write infrequently (if so building an index is not such a bad idea).

Comment: reading a lot and writing almost never, but perhaps now and then. great ideas - thanks!